# Angular 2 - Cancelling a subscription after a timeout

Tags: angular, http, typescript, angular2-services

I want to ignore a response from my API if it is taking too long. I use

```
this.http.get(mysqlUrl).subscribe()
```

to get the response. But I want to cancel that subscription if it takes longer than 5 seconds to finish. I know I can use unsubscribe(), but how can I link that to a timeout value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A plain `setTimeout` should work:

```
let subscription = this.http.get(mysqlUrl).subscribe(...);

setTimeout(() => subscription.unsubscribe(), 5000);
```

Comment: I have used setTimeout() myself a lot, but the trend seems to be not to use setTimeout in companion with Angular (at least, with AngularJS there is the $timeout service)...

Comment: I think people just don't like when `setTimeout` is used as a hack. But in this particular case, you actually want to wait for a timeout. Also, Angular 2 patches async functions like `setTimeout`, so it behaves like `$timeout` in Angular 1.

Comment: The solution provided by Frank Modica is also mentioned here https://angular.io/guide/observables so i consider this the correct solution

Answer (score 10):

You could use the takeUntil operator:

```
this.http.get(mysqlUrl)
    .takeUntil(Observable.of(true).delay(5000))
    .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: The more I use `rxjs` the more I like this answer, since you don't have to store the subscription in a variable. I'm just not crazy about having to do `import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil'; import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'; import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay'`. But if I was managing many subscriptions I might use this solution.

Comment: For me the takeUntil didn't stop after 5 seconds. My scenario involved using a clickstream in conjunction with a switchmap, The clickstream meant I wanted to cancel any ongoing requests if another click came in before first completed..

Answer (score 3):

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout`

```
this.http.get(mysqlUrl)
    .timeout(5000)
    .subscribe()
```

Comment: If you have a successful subscription - ie response is returned, before the 5 seconds your error handling kicks in too after the 5 seconds as well, so I'm not such a fan of this approach. It's a shame the successful subscribe doesn't just automatically end the timeout and that was it...

Comment: `.take(1)` might fix that.